# get_result()->fetch_assoc() returns 0 even thought num rows is 2

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I have a function that accesses the database to get a message based on the recipients UserID.

```
function GetUnreadMessages($recipientID, $db) {
  $sql  = 'SELECT
                senderID AND headline AND message
            FROM
                Message
            WHERE
                 recipientID = ? AND unread = 1
            LIMIT 100';
  $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
  if ($stmt) {
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $recipientID);
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt->get_result();
  }
  else {
    http_redirect("", array(
    section => "info",
    message => "Internal error while recieving messages!"
    ));
  }
}
```

Then I call this. `$messageCount` is 2 like it should be because there are two messages for my testuser.

```
 $messages = GetUnreadMessages($userID, $db);
 $messageCount =  $messages->num_rows;  // 2
```

But when I call this `$messages` is always 0. Any idea why?

```
 $message = $messages->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC);  // 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gives you the logical AND of the values as one result:

```
select senderID AND headline AND message
```

You want this:

```
select senderID, headline, message
```

Answer (score 2):

You separate fields with `,` not `AND`.

```
SELECT senderID, headline, message
```